# Cloudant Query choosing the wrong index

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm using the following end-point to see which index is being chosen by cloudant to fetch my results:

```
https://mydb.cloudant.com/mlslistings-temp/_explain
```

and here's an example query for which wrong index is being chosen:

```
{
 "sort": ["ListPrice"],
 "limit":20,
 "selector":{
     "Street#":"1031",
     "MLSStatus":{"$or":[{"$eq":"Active"}]},
     "ListPrice":{"$gte":0},
     "ParcelSizeAcres":{"$gte":0,"$lte":50}}
}
```

All the fields you see in the query are `json` based indexes.
I have two questions regarding index selection:

- Whichever field I put as the sort field automatically gets selected as the chosen index. It would've been fine but mostly my query is going to be `"ListPrice":{"$gte":0}` which ends-up doing full table scan since almost all properties have greater than 0 price.
- If I take out all the fields in the query and just leave `Street#` and `ParcelSizeAcres` in the query, `ParcelSizeAcres` is selected as the index but that's wrong. Because when I run the query with `Street#` a total of 53 documents are returned whereas `ParcelSizeAcres` returns hundreds.

These index selections seem to be going against [Cloudant's Explain Plans](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#explain-plans)

Answer (score 0):

All your indexes hold a single field. So as far as Cloudant's concerned they have the same weight, and as per the documentation you refer to, the choice is then the first available index in lexicographical sort order, so in the first case, `ListPrice` and in the second case, `ParcelSizeAcres`. It seems consistent with the documented behaviour.